# Which disc(s) should I install for Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I've just gotten Grand Theft Auto V and it came with two discs. The first one said '*install*', the other said '*play*'. I inserted the play one and it says it needs the install disc, but I have heard that one of the discs messes up your game?

Which disc is safe to install?

Comment: Insert the install one (not to be rude, but it's kind of obvious if you know what "install" means).